# time_t was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'size_t'? compile error

Tags: c, plc

it shows do you mean size_t where time_t was used and others
at the end shows error compiling c files

I Tried installing openplc code form github using cygwin but the below error message shows

```
Generating object files...
In file included from Config0.c:6:
./lib/iec_std_lib.h: In function ‘TIME __time_mul(TIME, LREAL)’:
./lib/iec_std_lib.h:376:3: error: ‘time_t’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘size_t’?
376 | time_t s = (time_t)s_f;
| ^~~~~~
| size_t
./lib/iec_std_lib.h:378:21: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘ns’?
378 | TIME res = {(long)s + ns.quot,
| ^
| ns
./lib/iec_std_lib.h: In function ‘TIME __time_div(TIME, LREAL)’:
./lib/iec_std_lib.h:385:3: error: ‘time_t’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘size_t’?
385 | time_t s = (time_t)s_f;
| ^~~~~~
| size_t
./lib/iec_std_lib.h:386:21: error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
386 | TIME res = {(long)s,
| ^
./lib/iec_std_lib.h: In function ‘STRING __tod_to_string(TOD)’:
./lib/iec_std_lib.h:623:5: error: ‘time_t’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘size_t’?
623 | time_t seconds;
| ^~~~~~
| size_t
./lib/iec_std_lib.h:625:5: error: ‘seconds’ was not declared in this scope
625 | seconds = IN.tv_sec;
| ^~~~~~~
Error compiling C files
Compilation finished with errors!
```

Comment: Does your hardware come with an on-board RTC and battery backup etc? Otherwise using time.h is senseless to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You must include `<time.h>` for the definition of `time_t` to be visible to the compiler.

The error message is somewhat confusing: the compiler does not know about `time_t` but it has seen a definition of `size_t` that differs only by 2 letters so it hints of a potential typo or programmer mistake.

Comment: It is not confusing - the computer is giving you a tip

Comment: @0___________: the warning is *somewhat* confusing... a more useful hint would be `missing #include <time.h>`. Smart compilers should know about standard type names and not pretend the programmer mistakenly typed `time_t` for `size_t`.